# Contact Form 7 WordPress Plugin Not Showing Error Messages

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress

I installed `Contact Form 7`  `version 3.7.2` WordPress Plugin,

```
http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/
```

It is Prefect according to my requirements, But the Problem is this when i leaves all field Empty and Submit Form, its starts Loading,and Showing No any Error Message.
also when i fill all fields,  mail sent but no any success message.

any one who can figure out this.

Comment: I get it populated with text (which can be seen if selected), but the text is white on a white backkground? This is 7 years later still......

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open

```
/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/scripts.js
```

and add `-form` on line 10, so it looks like this:

```
$('div.wpcf7-form > form').wpcf7InitForm();
    });
```

All Problem will be Solved...
Enjoy

Comment: I didn't find the path of scripts.js in my folder

Comment: For others, it is currently under: contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js on line 31, where it is missing. Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

Try this for displaying validation error messages.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/jquery-validation-for-contact-form-7/

Answer (score 1):

The normal scenario is when form submission includes invalid inputs (e.g., required fields are blank or email fields have invalid formats), the form displays validation error messages.

[This post](http://contactform7.com/customizing-validation-error-messages/) describes how you can customize the validation error messages that Contact Form 7 produces. as

```
<span class="use-floating-validation-tip">[text* your-name]</span>
```

So you have to check the configurations and may that post help you.

Answer (score 0):

When you edit a contact form, scroll down to the `Messages` tab and make sure there is text in those boxes.